# Ｂさんといるところを評価されれば meaning

Tags: translation, meaning, grammar

Confused of the meaning of Ｂさんといるところを評価されれば as it just doesn't seem to make sense translating it. For context the whole sentence is:

> 君と話しているときには、コミュニケーション能力が高いように見えても、Ｂさんといるところを評価されれば、コミュニケーション能力が低く見えるだろう。

I know the text is discussing communication skills and I'm guessing it is trying to say even if the communication seems high..... the communication seems low?

Comment: Link to (what appears to be) the source article for more context: https://gendai.ismedia.jp/articles/-/57130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ｂさんといるところを評価されれば

in that context means "if I were to be judged [on my communication skills] based on [when I am with] Bさん"

「Ｂさんといるところ」 means "a moment/scene when [I] am with Bさん", and that moment is what's being (hypothetically) judged.

To explain the context, let's say we have three people:

- the speaker, S
- some person A who S finds easy to talk to, i.e. 「君」 in your given sentence
- another person B with whom S finds it difficult to keep a conversation going

Then S is saying that she might be perceived as having good communication skills when speaking with A, but on the other hand when she is with B she might be judged as having poor communication skills.